# Can a stored procedure with input variables display an output table when parameter is selected?

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

**Edit**: I think I need to add `OUTPUT` in my code, but where and how do I change the automated `Exec` script to return the table?

I have created a stored procedure with multiple input parameters, that depending on the input will produce a table output displayed in the results window.

The stored procedure creates without issue. But when I execute there is an error, as it's not outputting a int. When I select the stored procedure and execute it, I get this error:

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Parse error at line: 3, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'.

The automated script is:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [ana].[spPlan_Acitivity_Data_Select_Parameters]
        @PlanTypeID = 2,
        @PlanID = NULL,
        @FYShort = N'22/23'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

I can also run the script as is, outside of a stored procedure, with defined parameters and it returns the expected table.

Additionally, I am using SSMS as the Azure GUI does not work for me.

My stored procedure is scripted like below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE myschema.spPlan_Acitivity_Data_Select_Parameters
    (@PlanTypeID INT , 
     @PlanID INT ,
     @FYShort nvarchar(5))
AS
BEGIN

IF @PlanTypeID = 1
BEGIN
        /*From Base data monthly split for selected year*/
        With CTE_BASE 
        AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM [myschema].[BaseData]  BD
            Join ref.calendar CAL       ON BD.[date] = CAL.[date]

            Where CAL.FinanicalYearShort = @FYShort
        ) ,
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /*CONCAT column for join in next CTE*/
        CTE_Activty_Sum
        AS (
            Select  *
                    , Count(Case WHEN FinanicalMonth = 1 THEN EventKey END) AS M1_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 2 THEN EventKey END) AS M2_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 3 THEN EventKey END) AS M3_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 4 THEN EventKey END) AS M4_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 5 THEN EventKey END) AS M5_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 6 THEN EventKey END) AS M6_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 7 THEN EventKey END) AS M7_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 8 THEN EventKey END) AS M8_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 9 THEN EventKey END) AS M9_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 10 THEN EventKey END) AS M10_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 11 THEN EventKey END) AS M11_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 12 THEN EventKey END) AS M12_ActualActivity
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth = 1 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM1_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 2 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM2_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 3 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM3_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 4 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM4_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 5 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM5_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 6 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM6_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 7 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM7_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 8 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM8_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 9 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM9_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 10 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM10_ActualActivitY
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 11 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM11_ActualActivity
                    , Count(CASE WHEN FinanicalMonth between 1 and 12 THEN EventKey END) AS YTDM12_ActualActivity
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            From CTE_Base CB
            Group By [All Columns]
        ) ,
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /*Joining columns*/
        CTE_3 AS
        (
            Select *
                , Getdate() AS Runtime
            From  CTE_Activty_Sum CAS
            LEFT Join [myschema].[Secondary_table] AS ST        ON  CAS.CONCAT_Check = ST.CONCAT_Check
            Where PlanID = @PlanID
        )

        /*This is my expected output*/
        Select *
        From CTE_3

END

IF @PlanTypeID = 2
BEGIN 
 
Print 'Business' + ' ' + @FYshort
END 

IF @PlanTypeID = 3
BEGIN 
 
Print 'Internal'  + ' ' + @FYshort
END 

IF @PlanTypeID = 4
BEGIN 
 
Print 'Operational'  + ' ' + @FYshort
END 

END
GO
```

Comment: `EXEC @return_status = module_name` syntax is not supported in Azure Synapse. This is denoted due to the fact it's omitted in the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax) section for Azure Synapse Analytics and Parallel Data Warehouse. The only supported syntax for executing a procedure on Synapse is `[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ] procedure_name [ { value | @variable [ OUT | OUTPUT ] } ] [ ,...n ] }  [;]`

Comment: @Larnu Can you please tell me why you are commenting and not answering, since this comment seems to answer the question perfectly?

Comment: As Larnu points out, the `EXEC @return_status = [ana].[spPlan_Acitivity_Data_Select_Parameters]` is invalid syntax. You will likely need to modify the spPlan_Activity_Data_Select_Parameters procedure to include an `OUTPUT` argument and pass `@return_status` as a parameter on its EXEC call.

Comment: @Andreas  this is, in my opinion, more of a typographical error. Trying to consume a `RETURN` value makes little sense when the procedure has no `RETURN` clause (again, because it's not supported). As the Op doesn't explain why they need the `RETUERN` value, then I've not guessed what they want, and I don't have access to a Synapse environment to test; I simply double checked the documentation here and immediately found *why* they are getting the error

Comment: @Larnu, sorry if I wasn't clear. I am expecting the table output from. This is in the SQL.
 /*This is my expected output*/
        Select *
        From CTE_3
I tried adding, OUTPUT in the script but it returned the same error.

Comment: What happens with `EXEC [ana].[spPlan_Acitivity_Data_Select_Parameters] @PlanTypeID = 2, @PlanID = NULL, @FYShort = N'22/23';`? Note the removal of the prior `DECLARE` and following `SELECT`.

Comment: No matter which planTypeId I input they all come out with the same error. I am working on this so, in truth, PlanTypeID 2,3 and 4 and place holders for the SQL that will follow when PlanTypeID = 1 works.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the Stored Procedure script, use the following script

```
exec [ana].[spPlan_Acitivity_Data_Select_Parameters] 1, 1, '22/23'
```

…in a new query, and the table will output.

You can NOT use the right click and Execute Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

AS @larnu said `EXEC @return_status = module_name` syntax is not supported in Azure Synapse also, in [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#examples-azure-synapse-analytics) this support is omitted for Synapse analytics.

> Can a Stored Procedure with input variables display an output table when parameter is selected

It will display an output table. but you cannot store it in variable. I tried to reproduce it and getting result as follow:

[image]

> I think I need to add OUTPUT in my code, but where and how do I change the Automated Exec script to RETURN the table?

You can try input and output parameter like this,

**Example:**

```sql
create  procedure demo19 (@PlanID INT ,@MANDT nvarchar(225) output,@VBELN nvarchar(225) output,@posnr nvarchar(225) output) AS
BEGIN
select @MANDT = MANDT,@VBELN = VBELN,@posnr = posnr from lips where MANDT = @PlanID
End

declare @MANDT varchar(225), @VBELN varchar(225), @posnr varchar(225)
exec demo19 510, @MANDT output, @VBELN output, @posnr output
select @MANDT, @VBELN, @posnr
```

Execution:

[image: enter link description here]